# MySQL 5.5 error handling / parsing

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I have read multiple tutorials and articles regarding MySQL error capturing / handling. Each document I have read mentions that in case of an error I could get the text of the error message, but none ot those documents mentions how I could further details of the error, for example the field which has triggered it.

My problem with that is best described by an example:

Suppose I have an app (let aside the programming language and how it is actually implemented) which lets the user create a new account, and let's assume that the account data comprises the email address and a login name. Both of these must be unique, of course, so the table which holds the accounts might be created like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `Accounts` (
  `Email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Login` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNI_Login` (`Login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Now suppose that a session does the following:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts(Email, Login) VALUES ("E1", "L1");
INSERT INTO Accounts(Email, Login) VALUES ("E1", "L1");
--> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'E1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The first of these commands works, the second fails as expected.

Now, if I would like to inform the user what actually is the problem, how could I detect that? In other words, how do I know if a duplicate Email address or a duplicate login has caused the failure?

Of course, I do not want to present MySQL error messages directly to end users (who are non-technical people). Rather, in this case, I would like to present messages like "This email address already is in use by another account." or "The login name you have chosen already is assigned to another account.". For doing so, I would have to know which of the table's columns field has caused the problem.

Putting together what I have read so far, the only way would be to parse the error string. I don't want to do this, mainly because I can imagine that the next version of the MySQL daemon uses different error numbers or a different format for the error string, and then I would have to rewrite all parts of the app which deal with error handling and reporting errors to the user if I would like to switch to the new version of the daemon.

Please note that I am aware that I could use transactions and test if the value which I would like to insert already is in the table (actually, that is what I mostly have done so far), but that leads to other problems with reporting errors to users which are even more difficult to solve (if there is interest for that topic, I will post another question and link it from here, but for now I'd like this to keep this thread as clear as possible).

Any ideas besides parsing the error string?

Comment: If you don't want to `"present MySQL error messages directly to end users (who are non-technical people)"` then do not allow them to work with DBMS directly (like via CLI), let them work only with your application that accesses DBMS. And inside that application you're free to do anything you want with raised error. That's most common approach.

Comment: @Alma Do: Yes, of course. Therefore, what I'd like to know is if I could get the error details (in this case, the offending field) from within my app without parsing the error string (the format of which probably is "subject to change without notice" (as a well known phrasing says)).